# React Native BottomTabs navigator not lazy loading initial screen

Tags: typescript, react-native, lazy-loading, react-navigation-bottom-tab, react-suspense

I just added `Suspense` to my `BottomTabNavigator` in my React Native app. The problem is that the first screen (HomeScreen) is not displaying - all others do. I see just white background when I navigate to Home Screen.

Here's what my code looks like:

```
const HomeScreen = lazy(() => import('../screens/HomeScreen'));
const ExploreScreen = lazy(() => import('../screens/ExploreScreen'));
const BlogScreen = lazy(() => import('../screens/BlogScreen'));

const BottomTabs = createBottomTabNavigator();

const BottomTabNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Suspense
      fallback={
        <View>
          <Text style={{ color: 'red' }}>Loading screen...</Text>
        </View>
      }>
      <BottomTabs.Navigator
        initialRouteName="Home"
        screenOptions={{
        ...
      }}>
        <BottomTabs.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={HomeScreen}
          options={{
            title: 'Home',
            tabBarLabel: 'Home',
            ...
          }}
        />
        <BottomTabs.Screen
          name="Explore"
          component={ExploreScreen}
          options={{
            title: 'Explore',
            tabBarLabel: 'Explore',
            ...
          }}
        />
        <BottomTabs.Screen
          name="Blog"
          component={ScheduleScreen}
          options={{
            title: 'Blog',
            tabBarLabel: 'Blog',
            ...
          }}
        />
      </BottomTabs.Navigator>
    </Suspense>
  );
};
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you figure this out? Having the same issue here...

Answer (score 1):

Well, I got it resolved. It may look like a hack, but it does the trick. Simply wrap the screen component in a Suspense. To do this consistently you may create a HoC:

```
const SuspenseIt = (Component) => () => <Suspense 
    fallback={
        <Text>Loading...</Text>
        }>
        <Component />
    </Suspense>
```

And now, instead of passing HomeScreen to the `component` prop of `BottomTabs.Screen` you pass  `SuspenseIt(HomeScreen)`.